# How do I get the corresponding data item when someone clicks a button within my data template WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am new in WPF and i need to make and application to show all the programs installed in windows. I found this [layouts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15705/FishEyePanel-FanPanel-Examples-of-custom-layout-pa) and i started to work in the fisheye panel, but the problem is that i want to show buttons instead of images in the layout, so I started to figure it out how to do that and i get to show buttons instead of pictures with the next code:

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Margin="5" Padding="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding Command}" Width="{Binding XPath=@Width}"
                    Height="{Binding XPath=@Height}" Content="App"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

My problem is: How do i bind every button to the corresponding action? and how can i know which one was pressed or the id of the button?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `TemplatedParent` in my mind.  The `TemplatedParent` property gives you an item which this template is applied. Use this code

```
 <Button Margin="5" Padding="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent} , Path=Command}"
         Width="{Binding XPath=@Width}" Height="{Binding XPath=@Height}"
         Content="App"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following,

http://www.actiprosoftware.com/community/thread/3513/using-button-in-datatemplate-binding-command